# Finding the exact value of g(x)= $\sqrt{x}$ at x=5 using derivatives

Tags: derivatives

The problem requires me to use the altered form of the derivative which is $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$. I know Im supposed to rationalize the numerator since I will get 0 in the denominator if i just plug it in but the problem is that the denominator becomes very complicated and I don't know how to reduce the equation.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't get how the question relates to the title. Also, the exact value of $g$ at $5$ is $\sqrt 5$.

Comment: The exact value of $g(5) = \sqrt 5$  are you looking for $g'(5)$ derived from the difference quotient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for $g'(5)$?

$g(x) = \sqrt x$

$g'(5) = $$\lim_\limits{x\to5}\frac {g(x) - g(5)}{x-5}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to5}\frac {\sqrt x - \sqrt 5}{x-5}$

Multily by $\frac {\sqrt x + \sqrt 5}{\sqrt x + \sqrt 5}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to5}\frac {x - 5}{(x-5)(\sqrt x + \sqrt 5)}\\
\lim_\limits{x\to5}\frac {1}{\sqrt x + \sqrt 5}\\
\frac {1}{2\sqrt5}$

Denominator doesn't become so complicated.
You will be simplifying far more complicated expressions very soon.  Keep your work neat, and progress in steps small enough to keep track.